# Pass data to a popover in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic5

In Ionic 3, passing data to a popover was as simple as:

```
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, {key1:value1, key2: value2});
```

and it could be retrieved with `navParams`

How do you achieve the same in Ionic 5? The documentation says nothing about passing data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured since we're dealing with parent and child components much like with modals, I'd adapt the [documented modal method of passing and retrieving data](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) (i.e. using the `componentProps` property):

```
  this.popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: popoverComponent,
      componentProps: {key1: value1}
  });
```

And to get the data passed, I simply set it as an `@Input()`:

```
export class ModalPage {

  // Data passed in by componentProps
  @Input() key1: string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Click to show popup

```
showPopup(){
        this.popoverController.create({
          component: PopupPage,
          translucent: true,
          cssClass: '',
          mode: 'ios',
          componentProps: { key1:value1, key2: value2 }
        }).then((popover: any) => {
          popover.present();
        });
}


Get Popup Data page(popup.page.ts)

constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
const key1= this.navParams.get('key1');
const key2 = this.navParams.get('key2 ');
}
```